# Find Duplicates in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates

Somehow there are duplicate entries in my table. Data structure is set-up like this:

```
RecordID, UserID, clockin, clockout
```

So if one user has 2 entries with the same `clockin/clockout` time then it is a duplicate.  A duplicate would look like this. The entry should only exist once, and the `clockin & clock` out time are exactly the same.

```
RecordID  UserID  clockin              clockout
1         16      2015-01-12 07:15:23  2015-01-12 08:55:15
2         16      2015-01-12 07:15:23  2015-01-12 08:55:15
3         44      2014-12-18 08:02:36  2014-12-18 04:02:36
4         44      2014-12-18 08:02:36  2014-12-18 04:02:36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `row_number` window function:

```
with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by UserID, clockin, clockout 
                                        order by RecordID ) as rn from TableName)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find the duplicated records and delete them, leaving only one record for each combination of `UserId`, `clockin`, `clockout` values.

```
DELETE 
FROM MyTable
WHERE RecordId IN(
    SELECT t1.RecordId
    FROM MyTable t1
    INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON(t1.UserId = t2.UserId 
                         AND t1.clockin = t2.clockin 
                         AND t1.clockout = t2.clockout)
    WHERE t1.RecordId < t2.RecordId
)
```

Then you should set up a [unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) or [unique index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187019.aspx) on the combination of those 3 columns, so that Sql Server will prevent you from entering duplicated data.